# Is there a way for CPack to put everything in a top level directory except for a single file?

Tags: cmake

Is there a way for CPack to put everything in a top level directory except for a single file?  Basically, I'm packing a project in a `.dmg` file using the generator `DragNDrop`.  Right now, I have `set(CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY ON)`, which does exactly what I want it to do, which is include the project in a single, top level directory.  However, I'd like to also have a readme file at the top level that explains how to set the appropriate environment variables and I don't want this file inside of the top level directory, so that the user can immediately see the file without hunting for it.  Is there a way to have every file except one installed in that top level directory?

Comment: How do you "tell" to CPack what to pack? Are you using `install()` calls in your `CMakeLists.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around that's ugly, but mostly works.  Basically, set the CPack install prefix

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/foo")
```

Note, the extra `/`.  That forces an absolute path to the root, which means that everything will get put into a folder called `foo` when using the generator `DragNDrop`.  Next, I have a flag in the CMake file that installs the ReadMe to the destination `..`

```
install(FILES ReadMe.txt DESTINATION ..)
```

In general, this is a terrible idea and will probably break things when doing a `make install`.  However, when using the `DragNDrop` generator, it will correctly put the file outside of the folder `foo`.  Anyway, I flag this in the CMake file with

```
set(CPACK_DRAGNDROP_README OFF CACHE BOOL "Install the DragNDrop ReadMe?")
if(CPACK_DRAGNDROP_README)
    install(FILES ReadMe.txt DESTINATION ..)
endif()
```

Basically, I don't know whether it's possible to only execute CMake code when running CPack, so I have a flag that I manually set when doing this trick.

Again, this is ugly, but it appears to work for now.  Certainly, if someone has a better way of handling this, let me know.